# Can I use a variable's value as a new variable in swift?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to set a content of a variable as a variable itself? Like for example

```
let variable1 = "variable2"
let variable2 = "Hello"
```

What I want is to print the content of variable2 using variable1? i.e I want to print "Hello" using variable1 which has a content named "variable2".

Comment: No, local variable names get stripped away during compilation. What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it might not be the best idea if you already know it's going to be a variable name. It still would work though, just have to be sensible with the naming convention.

This link might help,
https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide